# Web Application - Dynamic Image Rendering

Tags: javascript, python, google-app-engine

I am an absolute noob when it comes to Web Application. I am building a network visualization toolkit based on Google App Engine. I have implemented the Spanning Tree Protocol as a sample. This is what it does:

1. Take the network topology from the client as input
2. Generate a network graph based on 1, and render that image to the client
3. Generate the spanning tree using the MST protocol
4. Render the image of the spanning tree to the user

You can go to http://www.varun-c.appspot.com to see a demo. I have been instructed by my professor to stay away from javascript. If you notice, the application runs properly.

Here is the problem:

1. The MST protocol is a step by step algorithm. What my application currently does it runs the entire algorithm in the backend and renders the final result.
2. What my prof. wants me to do is to add a button 'Step by Step'. When the user clicks on that button, the entire MST protocol is run one step at a time so the user can visualize the actual simulation of how MST works.

I have absolutely no clue of how to do that. AS I said, web development is not really my forte. If my explanation of the problem isn't clear enough, kindly let me know. I shall try my best to explain it properly. And do visit the website once. It will give you an idea of what the application does.

**EDIT 1:** I got it working. For those who are wondering, I create a hidden variable 'iterator'  which I keep on exchanging between HTML and Python backend to keep track of the step number at every click of the 'Step by Step' button. At the server side, I create a simple data structure to store all the instances generated by my algorithm. Combining this with the iterator, the image is rendered. The link posted above now reflects those changes.

Answer (score 1):

Generate a series of images for every step. Then create a GUI that facilitates changing the image displayed by clicking previous/next button. It is [possible to do this](http://joshnh.com/2012/08/14/making-a-pure-css-featured-image-slider/) without any javascript, just using HTML+CSS.

Answer (score -1):

I don't understand the topic fully since this is definitely not my field of expertise. So I try to rephrase the problem like this:

You have to show sequential pictures to the user that are generated by your algorithm. For me this is a perfect example of a task which should be done on the client side, using Javascript and the canvas element. There are a lot of libraries for this. But since your professor precluded this way you could generate the pictures for the single steps on the server.

Not sure if these thoughts are of any help.